# Modernizr.mq not working in Safari & multiple event triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, modernizr

I've got a sub navigation that has 3 different styles and functions based on browser width. [See it live here](http://sommersmarketing.com/clients/kingswood/website-new/about.php).

```
$(function() {
 $(window).resize(function() {
if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width:641px) and (max-width: 1200px)')) {
     $(".subnav-menu").click(function() {
              $('.primary-subnav').slideToggle();
              $('.subnav-close').show();
     });
     $(".subnav-close").click(function() {
              $('.primary-subnav').slideToggle();
              $('.subnav-close').hide();
     });
     $(".tablet-subnav li").click(function() {
              $('.primary-subnav').slideToggle();
              $('.subnav-close').hide();
     });
}
else if(Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 640px)')) {
     $(".subnav").click(function() {
              $('.primary-subnav').slideToggle();
              $('.subnav-mobile-open').toggle();
              $('.subnav-mobile-close').toggle();
     });
   }
 }).trigger('resize');
});
```

The menu that should be showing up on click is not showing up at all on Safari on my desktop or phone, tested on several other macs and got nothing. It's working fine in Chrome/Firefox other than sometimes it will fire the menu's slideToggle multiple times. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:: The menu appears to not expand in mobile safari or mobile chrome at all, whereas I thought this was purely a safari issue. The little arrow on mobile and the menu button tablet do change though, and if I tap under there were the menu should be, it reacts as if going to the link, but the menu is not visible... Really strange.

Comment: try to add .stop() before each event. like $('.primary-subnav').stop().slideToggle(); and $('.subnav-close').stop().hide();

Comment: That seems to sort of work for the repeat triggering. It works until you resize the browser and try to access the other style of navigation, then the menu won't appear. I know this isn't an issue for users, especially our target audience, since they won't resize the browser once they're on the page. However, I'd like to have this functioning correctly if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.off( "click", "**" )`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) on the click event handlers that were added from one media query and replace them with the [`.on( "click" )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handlers that you need for the current media query.

Also, you can create a nice fade effect without the common problem of multiple queued animations by adding [`.stop( true, true )`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to the chain.

Without your html, I couldn't really test it, but here's about what it should look like:

```
$( window ).on( "resize", function () 
{
  if( Modernizr.mq( "(min-width:641px) and (max-width: 1200px)" )) 
  {
    $( ".subnav" ).off( "click", "**" );

    $( ".subnav-menu" ).on( "click", function () 
    {
      $( ".primary-subnav" )
        .stop( true, true)
        .slideToggle();

      $( ".subnav-close" )
        .stop( true, true )
        .show();
    });

    $( ".subnav-close, .tablet-subnav li" ).on(" click", function () 
    {
      $( ".primary-subnav" )
        .stop( true, true )
        .slideToggle();

      $( ".subnav-close" )
        .stop( true, true )
        .hide();
    });
  }
  else if ( Modernizr.mq( "(max-width: 640px)" )) 
  {
    $( ".subnav-menu, .subnav-close, .tablet-subnav li" ).off( "click", "**" );

    $( ".subnav" ).on( "click", function () 
    {
      $( ".primary-subnav" )
        .stop( true, true )
        .slideToggle();

      $( ".subnav-mobile-open, .subnav-mobile-close" )
        .stop(true, true)
        .toggle();
    });
  }
})
.resize();
```

Comment: I *think* this solved the issue, but they suddenly changed their mind on the menu style and eliminated the need for all this hard work. Thank you for your help though, this will definitely help a ton in the future.